# Apache kafka..produce and consume by the same application

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka, camunda

I need to have an Apache kafka producer-consumer rest microservice application wherein the once I trigger the producer rest end point i should immediately get an acknowledgement message and the workflow which triggers this service then waits at the next step (a wait event) which is to be triggered by the consumer application.

How can I implement this ?

Thanks and Regards,
Albin

Answer (score 0):

The tech-stack your are looking at is
 1. Dropwizard Framework : For spinning up a REST Service to serve the incoming requests
 2. Apache Kafka java clients to Produce and Consume based on Triggers

Step #1. Follow this getting-started dropwizard tutorial  https://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html to build a Rest Service
Step #2. In the initialization step of the Dropwizard start Kafka Producer and Kafka Consumer Threads
Step #3. The API supports a POST endpoint to receive the trigger events. Based on whether its a Produce or Consume, the Api resource can proceed with the handling the event.